# How do I set PHP variables as a specific color in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a user-defined language, and most colors are set up well, but I don't know how to set colors for variables

Example cases:

```
private $request = "";
$user = new user;
$user->setemail($email);
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings --> Style Configurator --> Choose php --> Choose VARIABLE and set foreground color as per your choice.

[image]